# A way around a Chron script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Is there a way to do the following in a SPA:

- Add User
- Update list of users, for all other logged in users, with the added user if they are in the User List Module of the application. Do this without a chron job constantly checking if there is a new user.

Almost like forcing a response without a Request. Is this a Unicorn?

I am trying to see if there is an efficient way of doing this.

Technologies are NodeJS, Express, and React on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting up a websocket connection between your logged in users and your server. That way, you would be able to push a change (like a new user being added) to all your clients. However, all the clients would still need to be constantly online. Try looking into socket.io as a gentle introduction to websockets.

You could also try looking into WebRTC and other P2P web technologies, though I'm not sure if that would help you in any way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will look into it immediately.